# Detecting time-shifted time series

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing, python

Assume there are two time series of real values.
How to test hypothesis, that these series are quite the same, but there is a time shift between them?

Comment: When you say "the same but with a time shift" you mean $y(t) = x(t-\tau)$ (where the shift is $\tau$), with no error, no rescaling? Or something else? Can you make your question more precise? What sort of alternatives would you want power against?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-correlation ?

Comment: @Glen_b, both, error and rescaling are possible. More precisely, there are two financial stocks and one instrument. And I have a guess, that one stock reacts on the situation faster than the other.

Comment: I fear I understand less than before. Are you able to write the relationship you mean algebraically (including shift and scale and however the instrument is coming in) or at least describe it precisely enough that I could be confident in writing it? I'm guessing you're considering two situations, one where a stock reacts more quickly and one where it doesn't. Without knowing what it's reacting to, it may be difficult to tell from noise.

Comment: @Glen_b,there are two bitcoin stocks. And there are two timeseries - bitocoin\usd rates. And I'd like to tell something about one rate, looking at another. The absolute values of the rates are different, but there may be a link between oscillations. I have a guess to be tested about a slight delay in reacting to real-world events. Hope it made the question a bit clearer.

Comment: You might look into dynamic time warping.

Answer (score 1):

You could start by looking at Cross-Correlation between the time-series.

Here is how to do it in Python:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6991471/computing-cross-correlation-function

Comment: even better why you shouldn't look at the CCF between the time series ! https://www.jstor.org/stable/2341482?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents